# How can I make this Abstract Lights Background in Cycles Rendering?

Tags: lighting

[image]
I am a beginner at Blender, so this might be more than I can chew but I am giving it everything I have got.
I have tried almost every trick, way and guide on YouTube, Forums (CGCookie, Reddit, here and more), but none of them has helped me to achieve anything close to this.

Things that I have tried to do:

1. Used Bezier Paths, gave them geometry then played a lot with the material. But couldn't get the emission to fade away at the edges of the path or make the edges of the path blurry. My output was very not nearly as soft like image attached.
2. Tried Material shader inside volume instead on surface, better results. The edges were smooth and the emission faded much more accurately. However, the object didn't conceive the same results at different scales.
3. Tried to model a plane like reference and give it a transparent and an emission shader. Somewhat decent results but upon trying to blur or fade the edges, the emission went down considerably.

If there is a way to achieve 80-90% of pic rel, I'll be glad.
Thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66853/northern-lights-effect-along-line-on-textured-plane https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67703/create-a-plasma-like-effect-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53032/how-do-you-use-blender-to-make-pokemon-attacks-like-hyper-beam-and-solar-beam https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/abstract-wave-with-particle-system

Comment: Thank you. I found your links helpful. However, I still can't figure out how to mimic the blue streak in the lower part of the pic rel. The fading at the edges and the blurring of the blue streak is challenging at the moment. Do you have any guides for that?